# What does it mean for a function to tend uniformly to $\infty$ on every compact set?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How can I show that the sequence of functions given by $\{z^n\}$ for $n \geq 0$ converge uniformly to $\infty$ in every compact subset of the region $|z|>1$?

If we consider the Riemann sphere, the point at infinity can be a point like any other. I get that. What should we do to show uniform convergence to $\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U \subseteq \{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| > 1\}$ be compact. By Heine-Borel theorem, $U$ is closed and bounded. Since the continuous image of a compact set is compact, the mapping $z \mapsto |z|$ maps $U$ to a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which has a minimum greater than $1$. Let this minimum be $r$.

We wish to show that $\forall c > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{W}\mid \forall z \in U, \forall k \geq n, |z^k| > c$. That will establish the uniform convergence to $\infty$.

Since $|z| \geq r > 1$ for all $z \in U$, $|z^k| \geq |z^n| \geq r^n$. Since $r > 1$, we can let $n > \log_r c$. Then $|z^k| > c$ for all $k \geq n$. Uniformness follows from the fact that $n$ is independent of $z$.

Comment: Thank you. However, how/where did you get your definition of uniform convergence *to infinity* in your second paragraph?

Comment: @mathjacks Uniform convergence means that the rate of convergence is independent of $z$, and the rest is the same as pointwise convergence. I think you already know pointwise convergence to infinity.